# Printing contents of another page

Tags: javascript, html, printing, dom-events

In the following link

```
<a href=\"#\" onclick=javascript:print(\"\") style=\"color:blue;\">Print</a>"
<script>
 function print()
 {
      //How to print the contents of another page
 }
```

Answer (score -12, accepted):

[I think you can print the contents of the current page not external page.](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/newtech2.shtml)

Comment: We can also print the contents of other page using URL with iframe.
Check [this stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13724670/5485645)

Comment: We can print content of other page please check  stackoverflow link –(https://stackoverflow.com/a/51306322/4225796)

Answer (score 30):

I know it´s an old question, but you can do it like this:

```
function printExternal(url) {
    var printWindow = window.open( url, 'Print', 'left=200, top=200, width=950, height=500, toolbar=0, resizable=0');
    printWindow.addEventListener('load', function(){
        printWindow.print();
        printWindow.close();
    }, true);
}
```

Tested in Firefox and Chrome. IE9 doesn´t work.

---

### Edit 2020-04-03

No longer work on Chrome, code adapted from [Coder answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35163081):

```
function printExternal(url) {
    var printWindow = window.open( url, 'Print', 'left=200, top=200, width=950, height=500, toolbar=0, resizable=0');

    printWindow.addEventListener('load', function() {
        if (Boolean(printWindow.chrome)) {
            printWindow.print();
            setTimeout(function(){
                printWindow.close();
            }, 500);
        } else {
            printWindow.print();
            printWindow.close();
        }
    }, true);
}
```

Comment: I would say many thanks to you. This trick works for me. It really helps for kiosk mode at chrome..

Comment: This method works but redirects my main page to the index page.

Comment: In Chrome 55.0.2883.59 it spawns the window, doesn't print then closes.

Comment: can anybody clarify the url format, like if the file location is in localhost and the file type is php

Comment: The url is the url you want to print, can be localhost or any url like https://firefox.com

Answer (score 23):

If you already have an external page( `letterprint.php` ), put that page in a hidden iframe and print the content of iframe by using onclick attribute in a button.

```
<iframe src="letterprint.php" style="display:none;" name="frame"></iframe>

<input type="button" onclick="frames['frame'].print()" value="printletter">
```

Comment: This worked for me too but I had to do some trick in the iframe because if I set display:none it does not print. So I set the iframe style like style="visibility:hidden; height:1px; width:1px".

Comment: This worked fantastic in current browsers, most eloquent way to do this without creating a pop-up (Which was the method I used to use) - needs more upvotes.

Answer (score 15):

An alternative is to link to the page with a get variable and then call the print function.

For your link -

```
<a href="print-page.php?print=1">Print other page</a>
```

Then on your print page (or all pages)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<? if(isset($_GET['print'])) { ?>
window.print();
<? } ?>
</script>
```

Comment: Oh, right. That's PHP. Took me a sec. If you wanted to stay in plain javascript you could do something like this: `if (/\bprint=1\b/.test(window.location.search)) window.print();`

Answer (score 1):

You can print external page by creating window object of another page and calling print method of that page.

 URL can be passed in argument or can be hardcoded in function depends on use case

```
function print(url) {
    var printWindow = window.open( url);
    printWindow.print();
};
```

Answer (score -2):

Think about the security/embarrassment issues that would exist if this was possible. Thankfully, browsers won't allow you to do that.

The closest you can get is fetching the page via AJAX, replacing the current DOM with the new page, and printing with JS's normal print() method.

Comment: not an easy way you are talking about for a newbie at least, what is the security issue by the way?

Comment: @phpBOY - The issue is immature website owners printing porno websites when you don't expect it.