# Print another HTML page using javascript:window.print

Tags: javascript, html, printing

This is the first time I'm using the following Javascript coding in HTML5, but my printed page is always blank and shows "about:blank". Can anyone maybe help me? The button I coded is the following:

`<a href="javascript:window.print()" class="icon-button print" target="LINK TO ANOTHER PAGE"><i class="icon-printer"></i><span></span></a>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I print different page using javascript/jQuery/ajax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23707251/how-do-i-print-different-page-using-javascript-jquery-ajax)

Comment: here is soution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578052/printing-contents-of-another-page

Comment: That didn't do the trick sadly.

Comment: Can you explain what "the trick" is? What do you want to happen? What actually happens?

Comment: I want the user to click the button so another page prints immediatly. Right now an empty tab opens and prints a blank page.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
the print function prints the content of the actual page, 
to print the other page you have to to execute the print on the load of that page like this :
<body onload="window.print()">
```

Comment: So I changed my original page to `<a href="link" class="icon-button print" target="_blank"><i class="icon-printer"></i><span></span></a>` and amended the target page to `<body class="size-1140 primary-color-green" onload="window.print()">` but it still prints a blank page. Any suggestions?

Comment: fill your page with somethings to see

Comment: I just tried this  and it works normally : <body onload="window.print()">
<p>drgfhyghfgh</p>
</body>

Comment: Let me link you to the files I've tried it on in Netbeans:

Comment: Original page: http://covicovastgoed.be/verhuur/woningen/h354-bovekerkestraat137.html - Targetpage: http://covicovastgoed.be/print/h354-bovekerkestraat137.html

Comment: I found the solution for you, it's that tag <div id="page-overlay" class="background-white"></div> causing the problem for you. remove and all works perfectly.

Comment: check the answer please

Comment: First time posting here, how do I do that?