# How to print an external page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to print an external source by clicking on a button. I found multiple scripts on the internet but none of them are working.

So my question is, how can I print a specific page by clicking on a button?

Now I have:

```
<iframe id="frame" src="./test.php"></iframe>

<button onclick="printOtherPage()">Print</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function printOtherPage() {
  document.getElementById('frame').contentWindow.window.print();
</script>
```

Comment: What 'scripts' did you try? What errors occur while you're using them? Edit your question, add what you have so far, error logs, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing a web page using just url and without opening new window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240472/printing-a-web-page-using-just-url-and-without-opening-new-window)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this:

1. Create a new iframe element.
2. Set the src of the iframe to the page you want to print.
3. In javascript, `contentWindow` is used to retrieve the document in iframe.

So use this code to print:

```
document.getElementById('frame').contentWindow.window.print();
```

Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Now I have set the id to frame. It is still not working

Comment: Is the frame document and the page of different domain? Pages of different domain(origin) are blocked to control each other by default

Comment: No it is from the same domain. When I click on the button it isn't doing anyting

Comment: Omg! Did you miss `}` symbol?

Comment: Hahaha, yes, that was the reason. It is working now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240472/printing-a-web-page-using-just-url-and-without-opening-new-window)

```
function loadOtherPage() {

    $("<iframe>")                             // create a new iframe element
        .hide()                               // make it invisible
        .attr("src", "/url/to/page/to/print") // point the iframe to the page you want to print
        .appendTo("body");                    // add iframe to the DOM to cause it to load the page
}
```