# Javascript - Programmatically batch print HTML documents

Tags: javascript

tl;dr I'm looking for a good way of batch printing database-stored HTML documents from javascript

Our users generate rich text content via an open source WYSIWYG javascript-based text editor (CKEditor). The HTML content is saved to our database and can be printed directly from the editor via its inbuilt print functionality (basically just window.print()) . This is great and works perfectly.

Now, we have a need to batch print saved documents and I am looking for workable solutions. There are various options that I can see, but all have large tradeoffs:

1. User selects documents to print. JS code loops through documents and calls print one-by-one. The issue here is that the user will see a bunch of print dialogs. Which is painful. (Aside: we are using Chrome but I do not have the option of setting it to kiosk mode)
2. User selects documents to print. JS code combines all of these in a single (hidden) container and they are all printed as one 'document'. These can be fairly big documents with tables, images, etc. I worry about the performance involved here as we could be adding a *significant* amount to the DOM.
3. Similar to #2 above, but at some point the documents are converted and saved to a single PDF. This would be OK, but there don't seem to be many good/cost-effective options for converting HTML to PDF.
4. Generate some kind of a report that can handle HTML content. I took a look at SQL Server reporting services but it supports a very limited set of HTML tags and CSS properties.

Is there a better way to batch print HTML content from javascript? Any help is very much appreciated!

**Edit** As per @Paul, I need to clarify a few points:

The content is that which is created in your standard online text editor. In my case:

- No iframes
- No animations
- No dynamic content

Now, were I to print straight from the editor a print stylesheet would be applied, so this may complicate things a bit.

Comment: something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/13724670/2418529

Comment: @NicolòCozzani This will suffer from the large DOM issue in #2. My concern is not opening a new window or not, it's a new Chrome print dialog or not. Thanks!

Comment: I'm fine with people down voting, but would appreciate feedback to improve future questions. This seems like a reasonable on-topic question to me.

Comment: The question is not clear because HTML can include inserted content, like `<iframe>`, dynamic content, like CSS animation, or content loaded or generated via JavaScript from `<script>` tags.  It is not specified whether the conversion must handle all of these elements of HTML or merely a subset.  The question also doesn't specify what has been tried or what is wrong with the way it is currently done beyond stating that manual approaches or multiple print dialogues are painful.  For instance, have you tried an automated browser like selenium or phantomJS ?

Comment: Is requirement to print single `.pdf` or multiple `.pdf` documents?

Comment: @Paul I will add an edit, addressing your first point. It was a good one and I appreciate the feedback. WRT the second, I have not tried anything yet. I am trying to determine which path to go down and figured I'd harvest the community's wisdom rather than trying to reinvent the wheel. not a good answer, but an honest one...

Comment: @guest271314 Ideally a single PDF

Comment: Client side you could get and combine all of the `html` `document`s using `fetch()` or `XMLHttpRequest()` within `Worker`, then post the combined `html` to main thread as an `ArrayBuffer`, create a `Blob URL` of combined `html`, call `print()` once.

Comment: Please specify what technologies are used server-side.

Comment: @NineBerry Right now, ASP.NET webapi as a passthrough to a SQL Server database. However, happy to use node instead.

Comment: Then I'd suggest using server side asp.net to create a combined HTML or PDF version of the documents, open this as a new tab in the browser

Answer (score 7):

Since content could be potentially large and consume a lot of memory I would do this on server side. Select docs on client and request server to render those to PDFs e.g. utilising PhantomJS. This would then allow you to even use mobile clients to fetch PDFs.

Comment: This is the approach I'd take too

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, thank you. Can you suggest any specific libraries to achieve this with PhantomJS?

Comment: @JP. Since you have the html, you could use nodejs combined with [phantom](https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node) to just display the html, See the [screen capture](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html) functionality on how you'd print it out as a pdf.

Comment: @Janne I'm awarding you the bounty as yours seems to be the most widely accepted answer. I'm going to keep the question unanswered until I put a solution in place, in the hope of receiving more answers. Thanks to all for their suggestions!

Comment: I have seen good results using the RichEdit functionality from DevExpress to convert HTML documents to PDF in a web server application in asp.net

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with the answer above, PhantomJS would probably be the best option. The only problem with this is in terms of reliability PhantomJS has been pretty touch and go over the last few versions. If the size of the documents become too large it may become too much for Phantom to handle (remember it was originally designed for web testing purposes, and morphed into web automation). When writing the script for this, I would suggest following the outline below (to break up the processes into more manageable steps)

```
    var steps = [
  function() {
    // step 1
  },
  function() {
    // step 2
  }
]
```

Again, it's not a perfect option overall, but it is the best one we have to work with for now. If you have any questions feel free to reach out, I'm working on web automation myself so this will all be fresh in my mind.

Download for PhantomJS [Here](http://phantomjs.org/download.html)