# Is it possible to open a standard print window without going to that page?

Tags: javascript, html, printing

I want to make a button to print newly created html page and print it staying in the index page of my website.
Now I have a workaround, open the page I want to print, immediately open print menu and then redirecting to the main page

```
window.onload = function () {
   window.print();
   document.location.href = "/";
}
```

Is there any elegant solution for that?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with Node.js.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing a web page using just url and without opening new window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240472/printing-a-web-page-using-just-url-and-without-opening-new-window)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is already answered here [Printing a web page using just url and without opening new window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240472/printing-a-web-page-using-just-url-and-without-opening-new-window)

MDN has a [nice example here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Printing#Print_an_external_page_without_opening_it)