# Print a docx file from url source

Tags: javascript

I have a table with rows in it corresponding to documents. I'd like the user to be able to click a "print" button in the table and have the browser open the standard print dialog (ctrl-P).

So far, I've looked at Print.js (pdf/html/image/json only) and [iframe methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240472/printing-a-web-page-using-just-url-and-without-opening-new-window) (just attempts to download the file) - neither work.

Is this doable?

Comment: `window.print()`

Comment: The linked question uses `window.print()` and as I've said, it just attempts to download the file instead of printing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I render a Word document (.doc, .docx) in the browser using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957766/how-do-i-render-a-word-document-doc-docx-in-the-browser-using-javascript)