# Page goes unresponsive in Google chrome while using window.print()

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I am using window.open() on a button click and window.print() is used on that page.
If I just close window with print dialog (without selecting 'Save' or 'Cancel'), parent page become unresponsive in Google Chrome.

It works fine with other browsers.

Can any one help on this?

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be a bug in Chrome version 34.  I believe they have since fixed the issue.

Take a look at this: [Javascript window.print() in chrome, closing new window or tab instead of cancelling print leaves javascript blocked in parent window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23071291/javascript-window-print-in-chrome-closing-new-window-or-tab-instead-of-cancel)

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly same problem with Chrome. You need to manually reload page:

```
window.onunload(function(){

window.opener.location.reload();
});
```

call onunload function on child window when closing the child window with print dialog.

Answer (score 0):

This is a know issue in chrome, Because chrome does allow you to work in background, update your chrome version to v36 Beta or v37Dev the problem will disappear.