# Window.Print() block other google chrome tabs

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am working on ASPx Web Forms Page and have problem with printing page.

I have button 'Print' which calls event (print method):

```
private void MenuPrint_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxMenu.MenuItemEventArgs e)
        {
Response.RedirectOn("Print.aspx", "_blank", "menubar=0,scrollbars=1,width=780,height=900,top=10");
        }
```

after I press 'Print' button it opens new window 'Print.aspx' and this is which is on this Page:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadData(); // generate print document
            Response.Write("<script language=javascript>window.print();</script>");
        }
```

and now it's the problem:

window.print(); will open google chrome printing menu, which block old window (that window where is 'Print' button. [image: issue image]

When I close Print.aspx by clicking [X] List.aspx windows will be still blocked. When I press 'Anuluj' - which means Cancel and then press [X] List.aspx won't be blocked. Eveything will be fine.

I make some research and figure out that there is no more options to print document, also I can't handle 'Cancel printing' button.

Question is how to avoid that block, maybe I should use something other instead RedirectOn?

Comment: Maybe offer the client a "printable" version but don't invoke `window.print` yourself? Or at least wait until `LoadData` has finished before invoking it.

Comment: Even when I register script with 'window.onload = function() ' it's still 'loading' status of window...

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a bug of Chrome 34 - is this the Chrome version you are using?
There is a similar question open here: [Javascript window.print() in chrome, closing new window or tab instead of cancelling print leaves javascript blocked in parent window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23071291/javascript-window-print-in-chrome-closing-new-window-or-tab-instead-of-cancel).
No solution so far though.