# How to print view AS PDF

Tags: jquery, pdf, printing

I have website bootstrap as scrolling - I need to print the view in screen as pdf 
I use this code to print all views

```
function printpdf()
{
    var w = window.open('printed.pdf');

    $(w).ready(function(){
        w.print();
    });
}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: this function is not working , how can i print ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing contents of another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578052/printing-contents-of-another-page)

Comment: no, i have one webpage as sildes i need print current silde

Comment: @salehshneiwer , then why do you open new window? Just use [`window.print()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_print.asp) method.

Comment: I'm trying to use jsPDF lib